# Unexpected error when comparing equality in two numbers

Tags: c#

```
List<string> slashesText = new List<string> { "Policies", "Tax", "-0.3f" };

string formattedValue = ((-0.3f).ToString()); // "-0.3"
if(slashesText[2] == formattedValue)
{
    Debug.Log("SLASHESTEXT EQUALS '-0.3f'");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("SLASHESTEXT DOES NOT EQUAL '-0.3f'; INSTEAD EQUALS '" + slashesText[2] + "'");
}
```

Hey!  For some reason, instead of passing the if statement, it returns to the else statement.

Debug.Log message:

```
*SLASHESTEXT DOES NOT EQUAL '-0.3f'; INSTEAD EQUALS '-0.3f'*
```

These are the exact same numbers, and they're both being compared as strings.  So why doesn't the if statement consider them equal?  Thanks!

Comment: It won't the `f` at the end, that is for formatting a literal, not for displaying

Comment: I've edited post to demonstrate your debugging efforts... Also "instead equals" seem to be showing different value compared what you wanted. It looks like you were  planning to `... INSTEAD EQUALS '" + ((-0.3f).ToString() + "'")`

Comment: [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't include the `f` at the end when you use `ToString`, `f` is the suffix used when expressing a `float` literal, not for displaying it's value.

To fix it, try:

```
List<string> slashesText = new List<string> { "Policies", "Tax", "-0.3" };

if(slashesText[2] == ((-0.3f).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
    Debug.Log("SLASHESTEXT EQUALS '-0.3f'");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("SLASHESTEXT DOES NOT EQUAL '-0.3f'; INSTEAD EQUALS '" + slashesText[2] + "'");
}
```

I've taken out the `f`, and used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, so that the machine culture won't give differing results.

Comment: I added CultureInfo and removed the f's, and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: I recommend avoiding `==` for strings, and prefer the `slashesText[2].Equals(formattedValue)` approach. This is to make it clear it is a value comparison instead of the reference comparison. I know `==` for strings calls `.Equals()` but it makes is more clear to the reader what is going on.